# Xamarin Binding Android JAR - duplicate partial class

Tags: android, binding, xamarin

I'm trying to create a binding project for OpenTok.jar so I can use version 2.7 with Xamarin. My binding project is unable to build because it generates two of the same classes. SubscriberKit.DisconnectedEventArgs exists two times which I cannot seem to Transform away.

Anyone have a solution for this or tried anything like this?
The access to the solution can be found here:
https://ebbits.tnmconsult.dk:9445/downloads/agrinord.apk

The error I receive is: "Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0111  Type 'SubscriberKit.DisconnectedEventArgs' already defines a member called '.ctor' with the same parameter types    OpenTokBinding'"

Answer (score 6):

If got help from Xamarin and the answer was to look at the parent of the classes (the once which references them).

The proberty was found in SubscriberKit.SubscriberListener and SubscriberKit.StreamListener both had a method/ event called onDisconnect which lead to two DisconnectedEventArgs classes. So once I renamed these two event to:
- SubscriberOnDisconnected
- StreamOnDisconnected

It worked. Code for renaming was placed in Metadata.xml and looked like:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.opentok.android']/interface[@name='SubscriberKit.SubscriberListener']/method[@name='onDisconnected']" name="managedName">SubscriberOnDisconnected</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.opentok.android']/interface[@name='SubscriberKit.StreamListener']/method[@name='onDisconnected']" name="managedName">StreamOnDisconnected</attr>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have been looking for a solution for a long time. This worked